# how do I get a random no between 1 and 100 in python?

Tags: random

so, I'm writing a program where I have to randomly pick a number between 1 and 100 excluding 1 and 100 in python, how do I make this happen? I've tried the randint function and the randrange function but both give me 1 as well as 100.

Comment: have you tried using use 2 and 99?

Answer (score 0):

So, you can write

```
import random
print(random.randint(2,99))
```